# Cypress.io - function visit takes a long time, it is waiting until all resources are loaded

Tags: google-chrome, e2e-testing, cypress

I am using a Cypress.io for end to end testing in our team, but we have a problem with function  cy.visit() very often.

The website has many resources from our server (css files, js files,....) and some external resources (js files).
If you open our website, sometimes it happens that external js file is pending (browser is waiting).

Cypress during the execution of  cy.visit() is probably waiting until all resources are loaded. And this is a problem. I dont need to wait for all resources, because for example this external js is for an advert and it is not important for our test.

Can i tell to Cypress something like: "After a few seconds after start loading a page you can exec this test without all resources loaded"?

I have tried onBeforeLoad combine with setTimeout and reload, but it failed :(

```
cy.visit('https://www.example.org', {
 onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
   setTimeout(function() {cy.reload(); }, 10000);
 }
})
```

I am so crazy a I dont know what do next. Please help me and sorry for my english :) Thank you! :)

Answer (score 7):

You can block unnecessary domains from loading with the `blacklistHosts: []` option in your `cypress.json`. Just add the domain name of the advertiser (and potentially anything else you don't need, like Google Analytics) to the `blacklistHosts` array:

```
{
  // the rest of your cypress.json...
  "blacklistHosts": [
    "cdn.my-advertiser.com"
  ]
}
```

[More information about `blacklistHosts` is available in the docs.](https://on.cypress.io/configuration#blacklistHosts)

Comment: It is now `blockHosts` (since 5.0.0)